# Is it possible exchange points between players using Game Center?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-center, xcode

I want to create a turn based two player game. In my game in a certain stage if player 1 loses he must give few points that he have to the opposite player. The game is implemented with game center. Is there any possibility that I can do this point exchange via game center. I am also thinking about creating a local DB can some one help me with the best possible way.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know the version of the sdk you are using, but in the latest version Game Center now support multiplayer games, witch means now Game Center can handle **all** data exchange.

Take a look at this tutorial: [How To Make A Simple Multiplayer Game with Game Center Tutorial: Part 1/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3276/how-to-make-a-simple-multiplayer-game-with-game-center-tutorial-part-12)

Comment: if this answer helped you, please consider accepting it and up-voting it. This increases your accepting rate and motivate other users to respond your other questions (and also gives rep)

Answer (score 0):

The ammount of "points" stored in the GS is always an integer number.
1500 points (I noticed that some funny boys hacked the game highscores for the IOS game "Temple Run" putting the maximum possible integer 237~.

Anyway a simple script would handle that example:

If player A wants to give $x= '1000' points Then

Check if Player A point count =< $x

If False end

If  true add value -$x points to Player A point count

and Add value $x to player B point count
END